# Putting Left-to-right reference in right-to-left document in XeLatex using BibTex

Tags: horizontal-alignment, xetex, bibtex, right-to-left

The whole document in XeLatex is in a right-to-left language, but all the references are in English. I want those references to be left-to-right.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `persian-bib` package.

Comment: Would you like adding a short example?